# Can "proving mathematical theorems" as a 1 player puzzle be studied in combinatorial game theory?

Tags: combinatorial-game-theory

In Combinatorial game theory other than 2 player games 1 player puzzle games are studied too. proving a mathematical theorem is a 1 player puzzle game. So I was curious to know whether it can be studied using techniques of combinatorial game theory and whether there is any work on this topic.

Comment: Actually, it's a two-player game between the verifier and the refuter.

Comment: So can it be studied? is there any article or something on it?

Comment: or can you explain  how it is a 2 player game?

Comment: See Wikipedia about [game semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_semantics).